# An example of a homogeneous, non-symmetric space

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry, homogeneous-spaces

A Riemannian manifold $M$ is said to be *homogeneous* if the group of isometries $Isom(M)$ acts transitively on $M$.

A Riemannian manifold is said to be *symmetric* if it is connected, homogenuous, and in addition, there exists a point $p\in M$ and an involution $\phi\in Isom(M)$ such that $p$ is an isolated fixed point of $\phi$  (that is, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $p$ where $p$ is the only fixed point of $\phi$ among all elements of $V$)

It thus follows that even though a homogeneous spaces are very nice and "symmetric" in the sense that all points look geometrically the same, they are nevertheless not considered to be a symmetric space by the definition above (at least a priori).

The inevitable question is thus:

> Is there a relatively simple example of a connected and homogeneous space which is **not** a symmetric space?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my favorite example. Consider the flag space $$G(k,\ell,n) = \{(L,H)\in G(k,n)\times G(\ell,n): L\subset H\}.$$
Here $G(k,n)$ is the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $n$-space, and $G(\ell,n)$ is the Grassmannian of $\ell$-planes in $n$-space, and we take $1\le k<\ell<n$. Depending on whether we're doing real or complex subspaces, this will be a homogeneous space with group $O(n)$ or $U(n)$.

You can check Lie-algebraically that this is not a symmetric space, or — my preferred way — you can find invariant differential forms on this space that are not closed (on a symmetric space $G/K$ with $G$ compact, every invariant form is closed).